# How to derive GetFeature URL from capabilities document?

Tags: coordinate-system, wfs, getfeature

Given this [capabilities definition](http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_umweltzone2007?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0) how can I compose a *GetFeature* request that downloads the actual geodata? I came up with the following URL referring to WFS 2.0.0:

```
http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_umweltzone2007? \
  request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typeNames=fis:re_umweltzone2007&outputFormat=GML2&
```

For some reason it does not accept `&srsName=EPSG:4326` as a parameter. Is it possible to create a download URL such as `&outputFormat=shape-zip` which I saw elsewhere? By now I use `wget` to trigger the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check the format section:

```
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptVersions">
<ows:Value>1.0.0</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>1.1.0</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
```

so we need to send 1.0.0 or 1.1.0 requests (hence reading version 2.0.0 of the spec won't help :-))

Next look at the output formats:

```
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>GML2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
```

so you can't ask for GML2 or shape-zip I'm afraid.

whcih gives me http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_umweltzone2007?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&typeName=fis:re_umweltzone2007&outputFormat=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/2.1.2

Reprojection on the server (i.e. &srsName=EPSG:4326) only comes with version 2.0.0 so you will have to handle reprojection on the client from this server.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was reading `<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>2.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>` in the capabilities document from which concluded I could use v.2.0.0 with the `GetFeature` request. Crazy how the `outputFormat` is specified. I never would have guessed `text/xml;%20subtype=gml/2.1.2`.

Answer (score 1):

The capabilities document you reference is the 1.1.0 response, if you want to look at the 2.0.0 capabilities you should omit the `VERSION=1.1.0&` parameter from the request, like:

http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/geometry/senstadt/re_umweltzone2007?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&

The 2.0.0 response tells us two SRS are available:

```
<wfs:DefaultCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:25833</wfs:DefaultCRS>
<wfs:OtherCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4258</wfs:OtherCRS>
```